# windows.open() is null while I call this only on javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, printing

```
  function print(data) {
    var printWindow = window.open();
    ...
  }
  
  function printWithAPI() {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/api2')
          .then(response => {
          })
          .then(data => {
            if (data.printer_name) {
              print(data.data);
    ...
  }
    ...
  
  printWithAPI();
```

In here, when printer_name is exist print function called. but at that time `var printWindow = window.open();` is null. why? How to fix this error?

Is that because of automatically running by javascript without HTML dom? I'm really not sure what's the problem.

When `printer_name` exist want to print automatically by javascript!

Comment: what is it supposed to open?

Comment: I am pretty sure `window.open()` can really only be triggered by user interaction - imagine an iframe just spamming you with new windows for infinity otherwise.

Comment: it's just a text file print
```
  function print(data) {
    var printValue = ""
    if ( data ) {
      printValue = data
    } else {
      printValue = document.querySelector('textarea').value 
    }
    var printWindow = window.open();
    printWindow.document.open('text/plain')
    printWindow.document.write(printValue);
    printWindow.document.close();
    printWindow.focus();
    printWindow.print();
    printWindow.close();
  }
```

Comment: if so how can I automatically call window.open() function?

Comment: [You cannot.](https://javascript.info/popup-windows#popup-blocking)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to launch this action with some user interaction. Most browser blocks this kind of auto popups.
Maybe you can add a button that starts the process?

Comment: Thanks, so there's no way to call windows print function on only javascript?

Comment: I've added button, but it only enable when printer name is not exist. if printer name exist print function should be called automatically!

Comment: For example launch an alert with an ok button that call windows.open. This alert can be programatically launched when you have the printer name. The you will have some user interacion to do the window.open action.